# No submersion of a compact manifold in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: smooth-manifolds

There is no submersion of a compact manifold in $\mathbb{R}
$?
Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following facts:

$1).\ $ If $f$ is a submersion, it is an open map because it is locally a projection.

$2).\ $ If $X$ is compact and $Y$ connected, every submersion $f : X \to  Y$ is surjective:

$f(X)$ is compact, and $Y$ is Hausdorff, so $f(X)$ is closed. But by $1).\ $, $f(X)$ is open, too,  so  since $Y$ is connected, $f(X) = Y.$

$3).\ $  Therefore $f(X) = \mathbb R$ which is a contradiction, since $f(X)$ is compact and $\mathbb R$ is not.

Remark: this works for any $\mathbb R^n.$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: sorry one question, why $f(X)$ is a open ? We don’t know X is open.

Comment: We have $f:X\to \mathbb R$, so $X$, being the total space, is both open and closed

Comment: I can’t understand sorry, for example X may be a closed manifold, why both closed and open?

Comment: Is $X$ is a topological subspace  of another space? If so, what topology is it given? If it is an abstract manifold, then as a total space, it is open and closed in its given topology.

Comment: I make sense,thanks